# Adding line breaks after image in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm new to HTML and am trying to create a custom landing page in Shiny.

Here's a snippet of my UI, but I cannot get additional line breaks between the image and the text. The image and the text render fine, but the breaks do not exist.  I've also tried blank tags$p() to no avail.

```
 navbarPage("",
               tabPanel("Home",
                    tagList(
                        tags$img(src="test_vine.jpg", width = "100%", height = "100%", align = "left"),
                        tags$br(),
                        tags$br(),
                        tags$p("this is a test"))),
```

Answer (score 3):

The `fluidRow` will solve this. Probably understanding the working of `fluidRow` would solve major alignment issues.

```
ui <- navbarPage("", tabsetPanel(
           tabPanel("Home",
                    tagList(
                      fluidRow(tags$img(src = "image.png", width = "100%", height = "100%", align = "left")),
                      tags$br(),
                      tags$br(),
                      fluidRow(p("this is a test")))
                    ## Simple way
                   # fluidRow(img(src = "image.png", align = "left", height = 300, width = 500)),
                   #  br(),
                   #  br(),
                   #  fluidRow("this is a test")
                    )))
```